# system.timers.timer autoreset default value

Tags: c#, timer

I just want to know the default value of this property.
I thought it was false, but it seems to be true.

I spent 5 min to look for this question and it perhaps make someone not loosing this time in the futur...

Comment: Use [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "The default is true."

Comment: I know, I put it in my answer. But it is not as clear as a good old fashioned StackOverflow answer!

Comment: The thought that every single .NET property is going to be documented in a SO answer is very, very depressing.  Especially to the MSDN article maintainers I'm sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it duplicates existing documentation that's maintained by a 1st party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from msdn The default is **true**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer from Reflector default value = **true**:

```
public Timer(double interval) : this()
{
    ...
}

public Timer()
{
    this.interval = 100.0;
    this.enabled = false;
    //HERE!!!!
    this.autoReset = true;
    this.initializing = false;
    this.delayedEnable = false;
    this.callback = new TimerCallback(this.MyTimerCallback);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was usefull and quicker than trying to find it on msdn!